# How to set a custom collider for Entity object in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I'm currently working on a forest map in a test level in Ursina and i'm using randomiser to spawn fir trees. But i want to decrease their collision box size a bit to be able to go through them as they can spawn close to each other. However, the method i'm trying doesnt seem to work.

Here is my tree class

```
class tree (Entity):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__(
            model="Assets/SimpleTree.fbx",
            texture="Assets/Treesnow.png",
            scale=0.007,
            position=position,
            double_sided=True,
            collider='box'
        )
```

And here i randomly spawn them

```
#-----RANDOM TREE SPAWN----
for i in range(-100, 100, 10):
    for j in range(-100, 100, 10):
        chance = random()
        if i == player.position[0] and j == player.position[2]:
            chance = 0
        if chance > 0.5:
            spawnTree = tree(position=(i+randint(2, 6), 0, j+randint(2, 6))) #small offset
            #spawnTree.collider = 'box'
            #spawnTree.collider.size=Vec3(spawnTree.position[0]-4, 6, spawnTree.position[2]-4)
            #print(spawnTree.collider.size)
```

In the comments in the last 3 lines you can see my attempts at directly changing the default size while creating objects, as you can actually address it via 'print()'

Also, I tried using the documentation method but it doesn't change anything if I use the default "box" collider.

if I disable "box" collider in the class and use the line below when spawning, the player has no collision with trees at all.

```
spawnTree.collider = BoxCollider(spawnTree, center=spawnTree.position, size=Vec3(spawnTree.position[0]-4, 6, spawnTree.position[2]-4))
```

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary research. See [Adding Colliders](https://www.ursinaengine.org/collision.html#Adding%20Colliders).

Comment: I know, I mentioned that the method in documentation doesn't work.

Comment: You should not modify the ```size``` property of the ```BoxCollider```. Also, you are misunderstanding the ```size``` argument of the ```BoxCollider``` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BoxCollider` approach is correct, but the values are wrong. `center` is relative to the Entity, so Vec3(0,0,0) would place it at the same place as the tree. `size` is also relative to the Entity (but not the model). I recommend pressing F10 twice while running the game to be able to see the colliders and adjust this.